# SPFx TypeScript json response from spHttpClient as array

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, typescript, sphttpclient

i want to get data to WebPart from the SharePoint list.
but some of the data are eg. PeoplePicker or Multiple line of text
and I have result shown as:

```
<div class="ExternalClass87D2C35DDC814159BCA3F4ACC1BFBC35"><p>Normal Text</p></div>
```

and here comes my question. How i can parse json response from spHttpClient to array, so later i can delete non usuable data?

I'm using the code below to get data

```
> private _getMultiLineData(): Promise<IDetailsListItem[]> {
>     return this.context.spHttpClient.get(
>     `URL`,
>     SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)
>     .then(response => {
>     return response.json();
>      })
>      .then(jsonResponse => {
>        return jsonResponse.value;
>      }) as Promise<IDetailsListItem[]>;  }
```

Comment: Are you asking how to get "Normal Text" out of that returned HTML? If not, please try to explain bit more what is the exact question.

Comment: @JussiPalo pretty much yeah, this is my destination. To be specific i ask how to get into the specific object returned by json so then i can get "normal text" from that returned HTML

Comment: @JussiPalo I'm getting from SharePoint List data via spHttpClient, the response is in JSON. When I print it to the WebPart it is (as shown in the question) in html. My problem is, how to get into that specific object to parse it to string so i can later edit it, to have only value i want.

Comment: As a side comment, I'd recommend using @pnp/sp library for the queries (https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/docs/items/), will probably save you lots of headache as you wouldn't need to manually construct REST queries. I assume it will also pretty much answer this question.

Comment: @JussiPalo I'll take a look. Thank You :)